# How to get sanitized postgres SQL string in python for later use?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a query that I want to append to a file (to generate a list of queries) that will be executed later.

```
location_filter="SELECT id FROM developers WHERE location='%s'"
out_file.write((location_filter, (location)))
```

But the output that gets written can't be executed in pgadmin:

```
("SELECT id FROM developers WHERE location='%s'", u'Seattle')
```

How can I safely generate this statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(database='cpn')
cur = conn.cursor()

location_filter = "SELECT id FROM developers WHERE location = %s"
out_file.write(cur.mogrify(location_filter, (location,)))
```